# SSL WildCard certificate shut down iis web site

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, wildcard

I'm trying to install wildCard certificate on a second Windows machine, after exporting it from the original machine i installed it on, when im installing the pfx file on my second iis and binding it to HTTPS port 443 on the second machine the web site gowes down and when i try to start it i get this message: 
[image]

any idea way?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to restart IIS service?

Comment: Yes i did, number of times and no change

Comment: Sounds like another service is bound to 443 port, thus, IIS cannot modify it.

Comment: I run netstat, didn't see any port 443 on the list

Comment: can you try different certificate to test whether IIS allows you to bind a certificate to 443 port?

Comment: I tried this certificate o a different server and the same result

Comment: Can you provide the output of the following command: certuitil -store my CertSerialNumber

Comment: Didn't install CA so i havn't got certutil, what should i do?

Comment: Certutul is a built-in command and is shipped with any system, regardless of CA service existence.

Comment: Ok ill look for it, but issue was solved after server restart

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for trying to help, the solution was to restart the server :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please mark following things..

--> Make sure the **SNI** is enabled on the server or else you need to provide dedicated **IP address** to that **site**.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have a dedicated ip for the website, and i tried it with and without SNI, getting the same result